# ¿Es posible capturar un clic y detener su ejecución?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buen día.

¿Cómo puedo capturar un eventos `click` o `enter`, detener su ejecución para ejecutar funciones previas y luego continuar?

Esto se debe a que tengo múltiples paginas `ASP`, en las que se realizan consultas, grabaciones, generación de `PDF` por medio de links, botones etc.

Necesito capturar estos eventos y realizar funciones previas.

Por ejemplo, he tratado con esta pagina donde tengo un javascript como este :

```
 <script>
    function onSearch() {

        onInit("nostart");

        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST",
                url: "RegistroHuellas.aspx/BuscarPaciente",
                data: JSON.stringify(numero),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    debugger
                    var resp = JSON.parse(response.d);

                },
                error: function (response) {
                    debugger;
                    alert(response.d);
                    var data = response.d;
                }
            }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

            });                   
    }
```

Trate capturar el evento clic como sigue, pero no funciona :

```
                <script>
                   $("#btnsearch").click(function () {
                       debugger;
                       new BstrapModal().Show();
                   });                 
               </script>
```

¿Cómo puedo lograr esto?.

**EDICIÓN PARA SOLICITAR AMPLIACIÓN EN RESPUESTAS**

Intente con cada respuesta propuesta y el resultado que obtengo al ejecutarse algún evento clic es el siguiente :

1. Se presiona clic, esto invoca la definición de la función llamada :
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
2. Se ejecuta la llamada al WebMethod que viaja al servidor 
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3. Se llama a la función jquery que se supone debió evitar la llamada al WebMethod, que es lo que estoy buscando.
   [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
4. La respuesta del servidor se obtiene luego de ejecutar la lógica de la función juery del paso anterior.

En esencia lo que necesito es detener la llamada de la función ajax.

Como puedo lograrlo ?

Comment: No, son eventos como estos:  < href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GV_pacientes$ctl10$lkb_paciente','')" >   o   como este  < 
  onclick="Javascript:onSearch()"  >

Comment: Evaluando respuestas ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Que te parece ocupar promesas y funciones async, una promesa es un objecto que puede o no puede devolver un valor y al ser usado con async/await puedes esperar a que se ejecute tu promesa y continuar con tu codigo, imagino que las acciones que quieres realizar son peticiones, puedes poner las funciones de las peticiones en promises, esperarlas con await y continuar con el codigo. Te dejo un link en el que combinan promesas y async/await para que puedas aprender mas

```
$("#btnsearch").click( async function () {
   await onSearch() // llamado a la funcion 
   new BstrapModal().Show();
});
```

Comment: Edite la pregunta para detallar el funcionamiento que obtengo al implementar la solución propuesta pero no obtengo el resultado deseado. Como puedo interrumpir el clic ?

Comment: modifique la definición del botón como sugirió @Luciano, pero obtengo esto : "Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function"

Comment: La instruccion await debe de estar dentro de una funcion de tipo async

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu codigo, no logro ver quien llama la funcion onSearch() pero en caso de que la llame tu click de tu boton el async debe ir en el click y el await en el llamado de onSearch para despues ejecutar el show del modal

Comment: La secuencia es esta... El clic llama a onSearch, onSearch ejecuta una función ajax. entonces, necesito detener la ejecución ajax codificada en el onSearch para "levantar" la ventada modal, esperar datos ingresados por el  usuario y luego continuar con el onSearch. Lo necesito asi, porque tengo que implementarlo en múltiples paginas previamente codificadas por alguien mas, por lo que mientras menos código modifique de manera mas rapida mejor.

Comment: Si la peticion es necesaria para que, con los datos que recibas o la confirmación que recibas, muestres el modal, si te serviria esperar la petición, ahora que si no es necesario porque no mandarla despues de que el usuario agrege datos y usar dos peticiones una para antes de levantar el modal y otra para envio de datos

Comment: Gracias por tu tiempo, desde el inicio imagine que esto estaba relacionado con el uso de Promise, aspecto de javascript que aun no domino; Lo que necesito es, que el evento clic del botón sea capturado, en lugar de hacer el envío levante el modal, esperar ingreso de datos y hacer el envío ajax ... Por favor podrias indicarme como se implementa esto que indicaste "_el async debe ir en el click y el await en el llamado de onSearch_" y que significa "_usar dos peticiones una para antes de levantar el modal y otra para envío de datos _"

Comment: Edite mi respuesta de esta manera el click se vuelve de tipo async y con la instrucción await espera la petición dentro de la funcion onSearch() y asi despues mostrar el modal

Comment: y lo de las dos peticiones seria dos peticiones ajax una antes de mostar el modal y otra despues de que tengas los datos del usuario

Comment: Gracias ... haré pruebas ...

Answer (score 2):

Tendrías que modificar como sigue:

```
  $("#btnsearch").click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      debugger; //no se que es esto
      new BstrapModal().Show();
      return false; // o lo que quieras hacer despues
  });
```

El `preventDefault` detiene la ejecución del clic.

Lo mismo con un `keypress` o alguna interacción con el teclado. En caso de los inputs, si quisieras, por ejemplo, validar ciertos caracteres.

Comment: Edite la pregunta para detallar el funcionamiento que obtengo al implementar la solución propuesta pero no obtengo el resultado deseado. Como puedo interrumpir el clic ?

Answer (score 2):

te comento lo lo que buscas es cancelar el evento, deberias usar  `event.stopImmediatePropagation();` de la siguiente forma:

```
  $("#btnsearch").click(function (e) {
     event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    alert("example");

  });   
  $("#btnsearch").click(function (e) {
    alert("no me ejecuto");
  });
```

Ampliación: Podrías sacar el evento del html y ligarlo a Javascript

```
<button id="btnsearch" class=" btn botonsearch " type="button" value="Search" </button>

$("#btnsearch").click(function (e) {
debbuger;
         event.stopImmediatePropagation();
        onSearch();

      });   
      $("#btnsearch").click(function (e) {
        alert("no me ejecuto");
      });
```

Comment: Edite la pregunta para detallar el funcionamiento que obtengo al implementar la solución propuesta pero no obtengo el resultado deseado. Como puedo interrumpir el clic ?

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar la definición del botón del html ?

Comment: Claro, gracias por tomarte el tiempo....La definición es esta  " <button id="btnsearch" class=" btn botonsearch " type="button" value="Search" onclick="Javascript:onSearch()">></button>>  "

Comment: Alli edite la respuesta.

Comment: Genial.... detiene la invocación de la definición de la función, pero aun se dispara la función ajax .

Comment: Es decir quieres cancelar las llamadas Ajax o cancelar la llamada onSearch()

Comment: El botón originalmente llama a onSearch, que a su vez ejecuta el aja, necesito detener la llamada a onSearch para realizar ciertos pasos esperar una respuesta ingresada por un usuario y luego continuar con la llamada a onSearch.